# how data string wrap on object inside ? work to html show

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
let data = {
  name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.\n Pariatur cum doloremque minima provident impedit adipisci,\n quasi dolores natus beatae earum, consectetur id ducimus minus hic. Voluptatem perferendis reprehenderit odit maxime?"
}


$(".question").text(data.name)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="questionPage">
  <h1>Question</h1>
  <br>
  <p class="question">123</p>




</div>
```

i want to string wrap my context on body.

not use br in body.

so use "\n" code but not work

and also use br but $(".question").text() not work

how data string wrap on object inside ? work to html show.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using `text()`  function it will accept your `</br>` and `/n` as text so use `html()` function

```js
let data = {
  name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</br> Pariatur cum doloremque minima provident impedit adipisci,</br> quasi dolores natus beatae earum, consectetur id ducimus minus hic. Voluptatem perferendis reprehenderit odit maxime?"
}


$(".question").html(data.name)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="questionPage">
  <h1>Question</h1>
  <br>
  <p class="question">123</p>




</div>
```

Comment: @Shawn- Happy coding